# Access ASP.Net cache for outside webapp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I'm in progress of optimizing a ASP.NET site by storing commonly used database objects in a cache and I'm wondering what are good tools to manage the cache?

I found http://aspalliance.com/cachemanager/ which seem pretty cool, but old? Also I have to install this in the webapp itself. I'd prefer an external tool? What else is out there?

(I also found Visual Studio 2005 add-in "Cache Visualizer" but download page http://blog.bretts.net is broken?)

Is there any way to access one webapps's Cache from other webapp running on the same server?

For example a typical object in my cache is the "type of user" (individual, company, student, etc.) that is pretty much static data. But once every year I might update this table and add a value. This is done in our admin app. Is there any way the admin app can access and invalidate "type of user" cache in the public app? (Without restarting the entire app).

I've looked at SqlCacheDependency but this won't work for us in this case.

Comment: The asp.net cache is refreshed every time the appdomain reloads anyway, i wouldn't worry about once a year updates this probably gets refreshed every few hours or so anyway.  You don't have to use CacheDependency classes to expire a cache you can just set an expiry date/time.

Comment: Even though the appdomain reloads (depends on your apppool settings) it still means you have incorrect data until it does.  How critical is it that the data is correct when updated?  You can put a lifetime on it.  Also, can you clarify in your question whether there's exactly one front end machine or is there many in a cluster?

Comment: @bryanmac: We're currently running on one machine.

Comment: If you're running one machine, you can offer methods to change the data.  Then it becomes a write through cache where the method updates the DB and updates the cache.  That becomes problematic when you get many machines in a cluster where the cache is inconsistent.  At that point, you need something polling to update the cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cache is specific to an AppDomain so if you have more than one Web Application neither can access the other's Cache.

You might want to look into external cache arrangements such as Memcached, redis or perhaps even ASP.NET State Server.

Comment: Would it be possible to build a "WinForms application" that you can install on the server that can access the AppDomain?

Answer (score 2):

You can still find the download for brett's visualizers using the internet wayback machine.

http://web.archive.org/web/20060512123557/http://blog.bretts.net/wp-content/uploads/2006/03/Johnson.Visualizers.zip